# how to combine the css selector using ":not"

Tags: css

how can i summarize the following css code? The current css code will display all li element as none.

```
ul.cmpro-accordion > li:not(.cid-2),
ul.cmpro-accordion > li:not(.cid-61){
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) in which you reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's about [specificity](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/images/specificitywars-05v2.jpg).

```
<ul class="cmpro-accordion">
    <li>li text 1</li>
    <li class="cid-2">li text 2</li>
    <li class="cid-61">li text 3</li>
    <li>li text 4</li>
    <li>li text 5</li>
</ul>
```

Css:

```
ul.cmpro-accordion > li.cid-2,
ul.cmpro-accordion > li.cid-61 {
    display: block
}
ul > li:not(.cid-2),
ul > li:not(.cid-61) {
    display: none;
}
```

<kbd>**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/PRmsB/1/)**</kbd>